# Iteratively open gensim word2vec models

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to write a function that loads/opens pre-trained gensim word2vec models stored in a directory.

I am able to load these models in one-by-one via

```
gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('file_path')
```

```
import gensim
import os 
input_dir = os.fsencode('User/Directory/') 

def iterated_gensim_load(embed_list):
    for file in os.listdir(embed_list):
        file_path = os.path.join(embed_list, file)
        model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(file_path)
```

In running the function:

```
iterated_gensim_load(input_dir)
```

I get the following TypeError

```
  model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(file_path)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1930, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 483, in load
    compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 572, in _adapt_by_suffix
    compress, suffix = (True, 'npz') if fname.endswith('.gz') or fname.endswith('.bz2') else (False, 'npy')

TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

UPDATE:

Following advice, I no longer get the above TypeError when I directly read in the file path as a string:

```
input_dir = 'User/Directory/'
```

Running the above function results in, however, produces a new error:

```
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(file_path)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1930, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 485, in load
    obj = unpickle(fname)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1460, in unpickle
    return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')  # needed because loading from S3 doesn't support readline()

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

However, each individual file in the directory can be successfully read in via, so I don't think they are corrupted/incompatible:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('file_path')
```

Comment: Why is `input_dir` initialized if it's not used later? What is `embed_list` when the error occurs? What's the full exact error you're seeing, with full traceback info showing the involved lines-of-code?

Comment: You do not want `os.fsencode` there.  Just store the string.  That's the cause of your problem.  `input_dir` becomes a `byte` string instead of a normal string.

Comment: If different code is generating a new error, you should either ask a new question showing the new code & full new error, or expand this question with the precise new info. If you're getting an error on a particular `file_path` value, the most useful info is: (1) what exact value of `file_path` are you using?; (2) what's the full error message, with traceback lines-of-code-by-line-number?

Comment: Especially: are you certain every single `file_path` generated by `os.listdir()` is valid to open? What's the list of all `file_path` values in that directory? Normal `.save()`s often generate *multiple* files in the same dir (including subsidiary `.npy` files), only one of which is valid to `.load()`. So trying to load *every* in a directory is unlikely to be a good approach.

Comment: Solved: As I am using MacOS, my directory had a .DS_Store file. After removing it from the directory, all models load in properly.

Comment: You can post it as an answer, and then accept after a day or two, to finalize the question.